# Auto populate field based on data entered in another field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to populate a field with values from two other fields.

The first is just a plain text field. The second is a select field which contains years (eg 2017, 2018 etc).

So, when you type into the text field, on keypress it should also update the field to be populated.

And when the select field changes, the value selected should be appended as '-2017' as an example.

The other thing I need is if a space is typed into the text field, that is replaced in the field to be populated with a '-'. And any non alpha numeric character entered is ignored.

I guess I am asking a lot here - but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you like fries with that?

Comment: Just a coke thanks.

Comment: Apologies...have I asked for too much here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy/Pastable code, should not interact poorly with other JS on the page. Built for one set of elements only.

```js
var outputController = (function(){

  function getYear(){
  
    return document.getElementById('selectField').value;
  
  }
  
  function getText(){
  
    return document.getElementById('textField').value;
  
  }
  
  function applyFields(text, year){
  
      document.getElementById('output').value = text().trim().replace(/[^a-zA-Z\d\s]/g, '').replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase()+'-'+year();
  
  }
  function setListeners(){
  
      document.getElementById('textField').addEventListener('keyup', function(){
      
          applyFields(getText, getYear);
      
      });
      
      document.getElementById('selectField').addEventListener('change', function(){
      
          applyFields(getText, getYear);
      
      });
  
  }
  
  return {
  
    init: function(){
    
      setListeners();
    
    }
  
  }

})();

outputController.init();
```

```css
.inputWrapper {

  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1em;

}

#output {

  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50px;

}
```

```html
<div class="inputWrapper">
<input id="textField"></input>
<select id="selectField">
<option>2017</option>
<option>2016</option>
<option>2014</option>
</select>
</div>
<textarea type="textarea" id="output"></textarea>
```

Comment: That is fantastic Trevor. Thanks so much! Is it possible to have the output in a new text field instead of just plain text?

Comment: Sure. Just swapped the output div for a textarea, instead of assigning resulting text to innerHTML, assigned it to the textarea value

Comment: Thank you. Thank you! You are an absolute gem.

Comment: No problem, if you don't mind flagging my answer as _the_ answer, I'd appreciate it. @R.Apps

Comment: Sure thing. Can I stretch the friendship and ask - how would I make sure 1) that the text is converted to lowercase and 2) non alpha numeric characters are ignored? :)

Comment: Are you asking to not allow non alpha numeric characters(?). JavaScript has a .toLowerCase() method just for that other purpose.

Comment: Yes - no non alpha numerics in the output textarea. Can add them into the text field, but ignored in the output.

Comment: @R.Apps - Used Regex to remove (hopefully) all alphanumeric and applied toLowerCase()

Comment: Fabulous! Thanks ever so much.